# Keras Sequence of sequences

Tags: python, keras, classification, sequence, recurrent-neural-network

Let's say I have an Input to the model as sequence of items: `[3,2,1,4,5,6]`. Then I can make `Keras Input Layer shape=(SEQUENCE_LEN, )` and then add `Embedding Layer`. But I have an Input of sequences of sequences of pairs. For example : `[[(3, 1),(2,3),(1,5)], [(4, 1),(5,2)], [(6, 5),(7, 1),(8, 5)]]`

I have pre-trained embeddings for first items in each pair and I want to have trainable `Embedding Layer` for second items in pairs. The second item in each pair roughly speaking means the amount of a first item in some context. Which first layers do you suggest to use to convert this problem to usual sequence classification? I suspect that I would need more than just a combination of `Embedding` and `Input Layer`

UPD: Even if I just concat these sequences into one, how do I cope with second value in each pair? What is the best way to use information about "amount" of items?